# Ipad - actionsheet not showing all buttons in landscape mode when keyboard is present

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am developing an Ipad application. It supports both landscape and portrait mode. The app has keyboard.It also shows an action sheet with 4 buttons when required. In portrait mode it works perfectly. But in landscape mode action sheet only show 2 buttons when keyboard is there .Without keyboard it show all 4 buttons. 
Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I dont undertand what you mean with "Actionsheet", but the trick here is that you have to subscribe to be notified that the keyboard will show and then move your buttons to a place where they can be displayed.